# php curl download file and get header

Tags: php, curl, header, download

i want to download file via curl in php also get headers of that.

```
// handler
$h = fopen($filePath , 'w');

// curl
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $h);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, array($this, 'getAllHeaders'));
$a = curl_exec($ch); // return false;
curl_close($ch);
fclose($h);

public function getAllHeaders($ch, $header)
{
    // check for 200 ok
    if (preg_match('/HTTP[\/\.0-9\s\t]+200[\s\t]+OK/i', $header)) {

        // header 200 found
        $this->header200 = true;
    }

    // grab all headers keys and values
    preg_match('/^(?P<key>[a-z0-9\-]+)\:(?P<value>.*)$/i', $header, $matches);

    // cycle
    foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_numeric($key)) {
            $this->headers[strtolower(trim($key))] = trim($value);
        }
    }

    // headers
    return $this->headers;
}
```

but i cant get headers and file not be downloaded. how can i solve that.

Comment: What does not work? More infos, please. Also, what is the response of curl if you dump it using `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`?
Have you debugged your `getAllHeaders` method to check if it is invoked and if so, with which parameters?

Comment: I think you're using `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` wrongly. This option reads the headers FROM your function. It doesn't pass the received headers to it. Check [the docs](http://www.php.net/curl_setopt) for that. You could use `CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER` instead and process it.

Answer (score 0):

The following constraints apply to getAllHeaders() which you do not satisfy:

> The header data must be written when using this callback function.
>   Return the number of bytes written.

Source: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#refsect1-function.curl-setopt-parameters)

How about:

```
public function getAllHeaders($ch, $header)
{
    // store header here (how about storing in a field that is an array of headers?)

    return strlen($header);
}
```